# How to tell if div is scrolling in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, uiwebview

Currently, I am firing a function when the content in my page div is being scrolled like so:

`$('#page').on('scroll', this.moveStickyHeaders);`

However, when using an iPad, the function doesn't fire if my finger is not causing the scroll (*scrolling automatically from dragging finger and releasing quickly*).  **What event should I bind my function to if I want it to fire whenever the scroll is happening** (*i.e.: bouncing and momentum scrolling*)**?**